# android_tutorial_camera not working

Tags: ros-fuerte, android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

we are trying to use android_tutorial_camera using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

We built rosjava_core and android_core according to the tutorials.

Then we built and deployed the apk on a tablet (running Android 4.1).
The app starts ok, but the camera topic does not appear on the computer running the master (by running rostopic list).

Any hints?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48463/android_tutorial_camera-not-working/) by [stefano.rosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3612/stefano.rosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have exactly the same problem. I use ubuntu 11.10, ROS fuerte and a samsung galaxy tab 2.
My tablet is connected to the desktop with a USB cable. I'm quite sure I use the ROS_MASTER_URI from roscore correctly.

---

Originally posted by [noe_vb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4546/noe_vb/) with karma: 26 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0